# rewrite rule on root index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url on only the root index.php file.  I do not want to rewrite the url for any directories.
I am using this in htaccess and it works as far as the rewrite of the index.php just fine.
I looked through stackoverflow, if this post already exists, I didn't see it.

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to execute this rule in only root directory you can use this rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Regex `[^/]+` will make sure to not match anything but the root directory.